# Combine multiple csv files (similar names) from different folders into one csv and bind them row wise

Tags: r, csv, batch-file

I have different folders with different months of data but same csv filename. Note the files have similar column structure therefore i want to merge them row wise one on top of each other.

```
c:\Folder1\abc.csv
c:\Folder2\abc.csv
c:\Folder3\abc.csv
```

In reality there are several folders hence i am confused how to efficiently execute he task. I don't want the hassle of copy pasting each file data into one csv. So i am thinking there is a batch script or R code to perform this function swiftly.

Comment: `library(tidyverse); map_dfr(1:3, ~ read_csv(glue::glue("C:/Folder{.x}/abc.csv")))`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow.  Please read the [tour] that you were asked to do when you signed up.  Also please read [ask] a question. Then come back and [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list.files` with `pattern` and `recursive = TRUE`.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = 'abc\\.csv', recursive = TRUE)
result <- purrr::map_df(filenames, read.csv, .id = 'id')
```

`result` will have all the data combined in 1 file with an additional column `id` which will differentiate rows from each folder.

Comment: great that works ! However the column names after combining are a bit changed for e.g if timestamp column was timestamp, in the new combine csv its showing as "time.stamp.."

Comment: That is because your column names have spaces in them, R does not like that hence it replaces spaces with `'.'`. You can use `result <- purrr::map_df(filenames, readr::read_csv, .id = 'id')`

Comment: awesome ! original column names retained... so basically map_df instead of map_dfr does the same job of mapping data into rows (?).

Comment: My last question in this series would be: what if i need to select particular columns from each csv file i am reading and then combine files using the same method as above.

Comment: Yes, `map_dfr` does the same job. You can use `select` to select specific columns. `result <- purrr::map_df(filenames, ~readr::read_csv(.x) %>% select(col1, col2), .id = 'id')`

Comment: dear ronak, i find several solutions for adjusting timestamps into R but its overwhelming and every data has different solution. I am combining multiple csv files (each with timestamp column and four other value columns) however in some files timestamp are incomplete and unequal value rows.. I need aggregated data in the end from merging all columns.. what should i do ?

Comment: You can ask a new question with some data and expected output. I am sure someone would help you.

Comment: thats a problem whenever i try to post a question  it gets closed due to simillar questions asked but condition is definitely different.